# Computing Instance Info for Auto Scale in SL

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am looking for java API for SoftLayer to get a computing instance information in auto scale page. (please refer to the attached picture)

I've tried the following code, but I can't get the information. 
How can I get the Core, speed, and network information using Java API ?

```
Group.Service groupSrv = Group.service(client, 1046365L);
groupSrv.withMask().virtualGuestMemberTemplate().hostname().domain();
groupSrv.withMask().virtualGuestMembers();
groupSrv.withMask().virtualGuestMemberTemplate().maxCpu().maxCpuUnits();
groupSrv.withMask().virtualGuestMemberTemplate().bandwidthAllocation();
groupSrv.withMask().virtualGuestMemberTemplate().maxMemory().sshKeys();
groupSrv.withMask().virtualGuestMemberTemplate().billingItem().itemPackage().name();
groupSrv.withMask().virtualGuestMemberTemplate().networkComponents().name();
groupSrv.withMask().virtualGuestMemberTemplate().operatingSystem().softwareDescription().name();

Group group = groupSrv.getObject();

System.out.println("host name : " + group.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getHostname());
System.out.println("domain name  : " + group.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getDomain());

System.out.println("getMaxCpu  : " + group.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getMaxCpu());
System.out.println("getMaxCpuUnits  : " + group.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getMaxCpuUnits());
System.out.println("getMaxMemory  : " + group.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getMaxMemory());
System.out.println("getSshKeys  : " + group.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getSshKeys());
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me:

```
package com.softlayer.api.ScaleGroups;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.scale.Group;

/**
 * This script retrieves information about Scale Group
 *
 * Important Manual Page:
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Scale_Group/getObject
 * http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Scale_Group
 *
 * @license <http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License>
 * @authon SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
 * @version 0.2.2
 */
public class GetObject {
    /**
     * This is the constructor, is used to get Scale Group
     */
    public GetObject() {
        // Declare your SoftLayer username and apiKey
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Create client
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Group.Service groupService = Group.service(client, new Long(777589));

        // Defining mask
        groupService.withMask().virtualGuestMemberTemplate();
        groupService.withMask().virtualGuestMemberTemplate().networkComponents();
        groupService.withMask().networkVlans();

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        try {
            Group result = groupService.getObject();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(result.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate()));
            System.out.println("Hostname: " + result.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getHostname());
            System.out.println("Domain: " + result.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getDomain());
            System.out.println("Cores: " + result.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getStartCpus());
            System.out.println("RAM: " + result.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getMaxMemory());
            System.out.println("Speed: " + result.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getNetworkComponents().get(0).getMaxSpeed());
            System.out.println("Networks: " + result.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getPrivateNetworkOnlyFlag());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is the main method which makes use of GetObject  method.
     *
     * @param args
     * @return Nothing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GetObject();
    }


}
```

Regarding to the network information,I just retrieve the **"Network - Networks >> Public/Private"** in the script

**Take a look this line:**

> result.getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getPrivateNetworkOnlyFlag()

**The Response:**

- True means only Private
- False means  Public/Private

I hope it helps. Let me know any doubt or comment.

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Scale_Group::getObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Scale_Group/getObject)

Comment: Thanks.. It brings only 1 core with "getVirtualGuestMemberTemplate().getStartCpus()".  How can I get the detail information of core like 1 x 2.0 GHz Core ?

Comment: That response is hardcoded, you should add "x 2.0 GHz Core", to the response that you get